# Specify animation options in [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition]

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, uicollectionview

I've got an iPad app that uses a `UICollectionView`. On iOS 8, when the device rotates, in `viewWillTransitionToSize` in my main view controller, I call `animateAlongsideTransition` on the `id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>` parameter and animate the frame change various views in the main view, one of which contains the collection view.

In iOS 7, I use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to animate the frame change with `[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]` call. I pass `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` as the options parameter, and the collection view animates the re-layout of its items as it resizes. But on iOS 8 with `animateAlongsideTransition`, only the topmost view gets animated; all of its subviews, including the collection view and its cells, just flash to their new sizes / frames.

My question: **how can I use or achieve the effect of `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` using `[animateAlongsideTransition]`?**

Answer (score 0):

In Apple's AdaptivePhotos sample they just call `setNeedsLayout`:

[AAPLProfileViewController.m](https://github.com/ios8/AdaptivePhotosAnAdaptiveApplication/blob/master/AdaptivePhotos/AAPLProfileViewController.m)

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self updateConstraintsForTraitCollection:newCollection];
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    } completion:nil];
}
```